# How to enable EF Core to return hierarchical data (self referencing table) with another KeyColumn

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity, self-reference

I have a table "CatalogItem" with a self-referential ParentId-Id relationship. A linq expression returns the tree of CatalogItems. But I need another Id column, e.g. NewId and not the Primary Key Id.

Table "CatalogItems"

- Id (PK)
- NewId
- ParentId
- Title
- ...
- Children (List of CatalogItem)

=> ParentId - Id (PK) relation works fine and linq returns a tree.

=> ParentId - NewId relation, then the linq statement only returns a flat List.

EF Core - Migration:

```
table.ForeignKey(
name: "FK_CatalogItems_CatalogItems_ParentId",
column: x => x.ParentId,
principalTable: "CatalogItems",
principalColumn: "Id",
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
```

EF Core - Configuration:

```
builder.HasOne(e => e.Parent)
.WithMany(e => e.Children)
.HasPrincipalKey(e => e.NewId)    // ???
.HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Linq:

```
var tree = await mCatalogContext
.CatalogItems.Where(r => r.Id.Equals(id))
.SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

EF Core returns now a simple list of CatalogItems and not a "tree" of CatalogItems.

Comment: The Solution is that the "NewId" should not be Null(able) (int?). Nnow I set it to NotNull (int) and changed the Linq Qquery to: `return await mCatalogContext.CatalogItems     .Include(i => i.Children)...`.